# Riemann $\zeta(3)$ convergence with Cauchy

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I'm an undergraduate freshman math student, and we were asked to prove that the sequence $a{_n} =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^3}$ converges (obviously, we weren't asked to calculate its limit.) Our teacher hinted to prove that it's a Cauchy sequence. We don't know much, only Cauchy, several sentences about sequences and limits and monotonic sequences and such (basic first few months of undergraduate freshman). I'm stuck. any hints / ideas?

Here's my attempt:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. We need to find N, such that for all $m > n > N$, $a_{m}-a_{n} < \varepsilon$. $a_{m}-a_{n} = \sum_{k = n+1}^{m} \frac{1}{k^3}$.

$\sum_{k = n+1}^{m} \frac{1}{k^3} < \frac{m-n}{(n+1)^3}$.
But this leads nowhere.

Note: We don't have to prove it by Cauchy, any solution (from the little we have learnt) will do.

Comment: Integral test shows that each $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^\alpha}$ converges for $\alpha>1$.

Comment: We haven't learnt Integral Test yet, or even functions (only sequences)

Comment: Ah man, but it's so good :D

Comment: If you are interested more in the particular value, there's a whole [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry's_constant) on $\zeta(3)$.

Comment: You are allowed not to post more answers...

Comment: In the OP, you wrote "Our teacher hinted to prove that it's a Cauchy sequence."   You were on the right track.

To continue, we have the following relationships: 

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^m \frac{1}{k^3}&\le \frac1n \sum_{k=n}^m\frac1{k^2}\\\\
&\le \frac1n \sum_{k=n}^m\frac{1}{k(k-1)}\\\\
&=\frac1n \sum_{k=n}^m\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)\\\\
&=\frac1n\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac1m\right)
\end{align}$$

which clearly goes to zero as $m\to \infty,n \to \infty$.  Therefore, the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy which implies that the series converges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $k\geq 2$ we have $k^2\geq k+1$

and

$$\frac{1}{k^3}\leq \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$

but

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=2}^n (\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{2}$$

thus the sequence of partial sums

$S_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k^3}$ is increasing and bounded, and therefore convergent.

Comment: This can be refined considerably, without much additional effort.

Comment: Another user has already posted the solution to which I refer.

Answer (score 4):

Using partial fractions and telescoping from your setup, after using the inequality $$k^3=k(k^2)>k(k^2-1)=k(k-1)(k+1):$$

$
\begin{align*}\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{1}{k^3}&<\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{1}{k(k-1)(k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{1/2}{k-1}-\frac1k+\frac{1/2}{k+1}\\
&=\frac{1/2}{n}-\frac{1/2}{n+1}-\frac{1/2}{m}+\frac{1/2}{m+1},
\end{align*}
$

which you can bound above with $\dfrac1N$.  (Inspiration came from the usual telescoping way to show that partial sums of $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ are bounded, which could also be adapted to show they are Cauchy.)

Comment: This is the way forward that I would have presented.  Well done!  (+1) and Happy Holidays!  -Mark

Comment: Note that $\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1} = \frac1{n(n+1)}$ to get a nicer expression for the bound.

Comment: @martycohen: Not sure if nicer, but you indicate a step in getting a tighter bound (which in some contexts could be more useful).  For just showing Cauchy, $\frac1N$ seems really nice, and then only requires dropping the negative terms and using $n,m>N$.  (In retrospect last 3 terms could be dropped instead of just negative ones, but either way the last step in this answer wasn't geared toward optimizing.)

Answer (score 3):

Since $ b_n= \dfrac{1}{n^a} > 0 \space \forall\ n \in\mathbb N$ and $b_n>b_{n+1}$ 
$$\sum b_n \sim \sum2^nb_{2^n} \rightarrow \sum \dfrac{1}{n^a}\sim \sum(\dfrac{2} {2^a})^n$$ which converges for $a>1$

Comment: I'm not sure what the $\sim$ is supposed to mean, but you can bound the summation as given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#Estimate).

Comment: Since the OP has not yet seen the integral test, I doubt that she/he has seen the Cauchy Condensation Test.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{n^3} < \frac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)} \\
 \frac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)}=\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{(n-2)(n-1)}- \frac{1}{(n-1)n} \right)$$

By combining these it is easy to show that your sequence of partial sums is Cauchy

Comment: I don't think this is right.  You may have meant to change the signs around a bit?  And using this answer with a bit of manipulation, it provides nice lower and upper bounds.

Comment: @SimpleArt Ty, fixed it. Ups.

Comment: This is a solid approach that relies on elementary analysis only.  Well done and Happy Holidays!  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

The integral test shows us that it converges and that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}<1+\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^3}\ dx=\frac32$$

And we also know that it is greater than the first term, since the partial sums are monotonically increasing, so

$$1<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}<\frac32$$

Comment: In the comments it states "We haven't [learned the] Integral Test yet, or even functions (only sequences)."  But this is one way to estimate the series.  The Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula provides a means to generate an asymptotic expansion.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, but I honestly wanted to do the integral test because it's quite simple and doesn't require much.  And if the integral test is too much, the Euler-Maclaurin sum is like bringing a hammer to baseball practice.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  And you're answer is fine.  I was leaving this as a reference for other users that might be interested and you might have been posting this solution in the same spirit. ;-))

Comment: Ah, well then, thank you :-)